# I can't print the contents of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to print out the content of a vector.

Here is how I declared my vector

```
vector<SDL_Texture*> hitCardsText;
```

Here is how I added variables to the vector, which also works fine

```
SDL_Texture *temp = loadTexture(ren, cards[dynamicPlayerCards[0]]);
hitCardsText.push_back(temp);
temp = loadTexture(ren, cards[dynamicPlayerCards[1]]);
hitCardsText.push_back(temp);
```

Here is the for loop that gives me the error, I have commented where the error is

```
for (int i = 0; i < numNewHitCards; i++){
    // i get imediately error where the hitCardText[i] is, when i chnge it to a temp texture, it works fine
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, hitCardsText[i], NULL, &hitCards[i], NULL, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```

How do I loop through the hitCardsText vector. I want to pass the values in hitCardsText to the function SDL_RenderCopyEx. please help. thank you.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? For example, what do you do *after* you push pack the pointers in the vector? Do you call some "unload" or "free" function on the `temp` pointer? Do you pass the vector *by value* anywhere? What is `numNewHitCards` and how is it initialized? Why don't you use the vectors iterators, or at least use `hitCardsText.size()` for the vectors size?

Comment: Also what parameters does the SDL_RenderCopyEX() method take?

Comment: we don't know anything about your loop since you have not shown where you interact with `numNewHitCards`

Answer (score -1):

To parse through the vector `hitCardsText`, you can simply use two of these approaches:

1- **Use iterators**:

```
for (vector<SDL_Texture*>::iterator it = hitCardsText.begin() ; it != hitCardsText.end(); ++it)  
   cout <<' '<< *it;
```

2- **Access element using operator []**:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < hitCardsText.size() ; i++){  
   cout<< ' ' << hitCardsText[i];  
}
```

Cheers!